# Is my following code correct?

Tags: mips, mips32, spim

Are the commands correct with the corresponding comments?
I'm having trouble understanding the mips assembly language such as what "Size", "Array", and "Result" means, also how I should incorporate them into my code.

```
.text 0x00400000 
.align 2
.globl main

 main:

lw $a0, size       # Load the size of array into $a0, using lw
li $a1, 0          # index i
add $a2, $a0, $a1  # a2 contains the sum, initialize a2
li $t2, 4          # t2 contains constant 4, initialize t2

 loop:

mul $t1, $a1, $t2  # t1 gets i*4
lw $a3, Array($t1) # a3 = N[i]
add $a2, $a2, $a3  # sum = sum + N[i] (sum is a2)
add $a1, $a1, 1    # i = i + 1
beq $a1, $a0, STOR # go to STOR if finished
    j loop

STOR:

sw $a2, Result[1]  # store sum at Result, using sw

.data 0x10000000
.align 2
Array: .word 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24
Size: .word 8
Result: .word 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of this is fine, which you could verify by running it. The problem however is that you hvae initialized the sum to the size for sum reason. Instead, the sum should start at 0.

Change:

`add $a2, $a0, $a1  # a2 contains the sum, initialize a2`

To:

`move $a2 $zero`